# I am facing some vulnerabilities issue while deploying React App via NPM

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, npm

New to React Js. Here is the short summary of my app, I created a small react app which filter the team members with the text input. It is working well in development environment. Which is working while start of NPM. Please check and where I am doing mistake or give me a chance to correctness of the process.

**My project> NPM start**

[image]

My site is loading in local or dev env.

Followed deployment process from this link. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/

But when I tried to deploy the site to GitHub, I am facing some vulnerabilities security issue. I have shared the step by step what I am currently doing. I see the issue is in the Mime Package. But I don`t know how to upgrade or degrade the package. Kindly check and guide in my wrong way.

**My project> npm install --save gh-pages**

[image]

**My project>npm audit**

```
 Manual Review
             Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve

          Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance


  Moderate        Regular Expression Denial of Service

  Package         mime

  Patched in      >= 1.4.1 < 2.0.0 || >= 2.0.3

  Dependency of   git

  Path            git > mime

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/535

found 1 moderate severity vulnerability in 1666 scanned packages
  1 vulnerability requires manual review. See the full report for details.
```

But Facing issue when I try to deploy to github account. Can any one help me on this.

My Package.json is also attached

```
{
  "name": "spiceliveteam",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": "https://nachisgit.github.io/TeamMembers",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "git": "^0.1.5",
    "npm-git-install": "^0.3.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "tachyons": "^4.12.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: These vulnerabilities are commonplace.  Specifically, are you looking for instructions on how to choose a specific package version (easily googled) or do you want to know how to fix a problem with a specific package?  If that's the case, you are better off asking on the GH page for the package.

Comment: @jmargolisvt, I have latest version of that particular package (mime) as I shared in the screenshot. I struggled to catch a small gap of this issue. I will checked googled too. But the result are upgrading the package. But I have latest.

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of R and D. I recreated the package.json which solves my issue. Thanks for who respond to my answer. This will help full to some one.

For creating Package Kindly use npm init.

Add the dependencies from previous packages and then proceed with build and deploy. Happy coding.